# Can test-results in azure-devops pipelines be filtered by TestCategory?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline running on Azure Devops that builds and runs tests for a C# solution. We use MsTest for test-runner, and we use the TestCategory attribute to categorize different tests. For example, we might have:

```
[TestClass]
[TestCategory("UnitTests")]
[TestCategory("SomeFeature"]
public class SomeTestsForSomeFeatureTests
{
    Some test-code...
}
```

and

```
[TestClass]
[TestCategory("IntegrationTests")]
[TestCategory("SomeFeature"]
public class SomeIntegrationTestsForSomeFeatureTests
{
    Some test-code...
}
```

Is there a way to group the test-results in Azure Devops Pipelines by TestCategory?

It is possible to group the test-results by Test Run, Test File, Priorty, Owner or None, but I have not found a way to group by the TestCategory.

I know that it is possible to setup the pipeline to run tests by TestCategory, but this is not what I am after. Rather, I would like to be able to get a subset of the test-results in my solution. Ideally, I would like to be able to link to the results of the tests in the TestCategory of my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that group by test category in test results UI is not supported currently. You can go to the [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to suggest a feature.

You can also have a try developing a custom extension for this. You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/samples-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fextend%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fextend%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) for official documents about how to create extension.